# Ubuntu 20.04 unable to mark as star to few file and folder

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

I am able to mark as star "*" to a directory:

[image: Parent directory]

But, I am not able to mark any subdirectory and another file inside the parent directory:

[image: Sub directory of parent]

I have checked for permissions: both parent and child directories have the same permissions.